# Как получить ширину и высоту используя attrs?

Tags: android

В визуальном редакторе можно устанавливать ширину и высоту View.

Как мне получить ширину и высоту?

Я как понял нужно использовать метод `attrs.get`, а вот который из них выбрать и какие параметры в качестве входных указать не знаю.

нужно получить layout_width

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = this.getLayoutParams();
    layout_width=layoutParams.width;
    layout_height=layoutParams.height;
```

### Не работает, я хочу получить ширину и высоту

```
    public class ShapeView extends TextView {
    Paint paint;
    int layout_width=0,layout_height=0;

    public ShapeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ShapeView);
        paint.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.ShapeView_shapeColor, 0xFF000000));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        a.recycle();

        this.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        layout_width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
        layout_height = this.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.e("asd",layout_width+"   "+layout_height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(layout_width,layout_height,layout_width,paint);
    }
}
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Указал 50dp высота и ширин

В коде указал так `canvas.drawCircle(50, 50, 50, paint);`

В итоге получил это, баг чтоли?

Comment: 50 в коде это не 50dp в разметке!

Comment: ну вообще для начала, радиус 50, значит размер круга 100 в пикселях и тут круг получился меньше, потому что нужно еще учитывать density

Comment: а  `canvas.getHeight();` вернет в пикселях высоту

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой вариант:

```
  view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  int height = view.getMeasuredHeight();
  int width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: mapView это что?

Comment: это то что вы хотите измерить

Comment: в вашем примере, что именно, вообще не понятно

Comment: эта строчка view.measure. Что это за класс

Comment: ЧТО вы хотите измерить? this - это экземпляр чего?

Comment: view - это любой наследник класса View

Comment: Выше добавил исходник, ваш код не работает, в XML указанно 50DP

Comment: А зачем вам тогда получать, если вы и так знаете размер??

Comment: Попробуйте вместо unspecified  испрользовать  EXACTLY

Comment: По нулям там все

Comment: от меня вопрос, если вы знаете размер четкий зачем вам его получать?

Comment: вообще в методе onDraw можно получить ширину и высоту c Canvas

Comment: Теперь стало яснее, когда Вы обновили вопрос, чего хотите добиться

Comment: Я пробовал через канвас не получилось, а вы как делает?

Comment: Вопрос обновил/

Answer (score 2):

Пока контрол не отображен в контейнере, он ничего не знает о своем реальном размере и т.п. Поэтому в конструкторе ничего и не получается.

Вот так в Вашем случае будет работать.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth(), getHeight(), getWidth(), paint);
}
```

Comment: Ну по сути рисовать и с вашим и с кодом  georgehardcore рисует, дело в том что получается какой  - то полукруг, и рисунок рисуется справа внизу. Что - то не понимаю, почему не слева снизу, это что новая архитектура

Comment: Все ок, разобрался, всем спасибо)